# How to know if an email is delivered or not in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio, deliverability, email-tracking

I'm using marketing cloud to send emails. I'm able to fetch user level email open & click report from marketing cloud using data views (_open & _clicks). 
Is there any data extension or alternate way exists using which I can fetch the list of contacts or subscribers against which email was delivered?

Comment: You will need to join _sent and _bounce. If the record (Subkey + jobId) is not in the bounce data view, it's mean the email is well delivered to this contact (mailbox or junk)

Answer (score 1):

The [_Sent dataview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5)

> Query this data view in Automation Studio to find the subscribers sent emails from your Marketing Cloud account.
>
> View subscribers who were sent emails from your account by querying the _Sent data view.
>
> Dates and times are stored in Central Standard Time. Daylight Savings Time is not observed. To view time-related data in your time zone, set time zone user preferences.

Comment: As per my understanding, _Sent data view only provides information of emails sent and not delivered. I checked this data view but no field provides information related to the delivery of email. Let me know if it's otherwise.

Comment: _Sent dataview is record of all sends that occurred, if they don't show in _bounce it is expected that the email was delivered

Comment: Keep in mind that a "delivered" mail in Marketing Cloud does not mean the email reached the inbox. An email that goes to the spam folder is considered as delivered in Marketing Cloud. To get more information about delivrability, you need to use other tools like ReturnPath,..